# Sharing an iOS app for Enterprise in XCode 4.1

Tags: iphone, ios, distribution

In articles like this:  http://aaronparecki.com/How_to_Distribute_your_iOS_Apps_Over_the_Air  as well as the official Apple Documentation:  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/FA_Wireless_Enterprise_App_Distribution/Introduction/Introduction.html it says things similar to:  "The manifest file is a file in XML plist format. It’s used by an iOS 4 device to find, download, and install apps from your web server. The manifest file is created by Xcode, using information you provide when you share an archived app for enterprise distribution."

However, in the organizer for XCode 4.1, there is no "share for enterprise option".  The only options listed are the ones pictured here:  http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/DistApps/DistApps.html

which are "iOS App Store package (ipa)" and "Archive".

Can someone tell me how I actually get to the "Enterprise Sharing" option?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just follow the instruction in the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/DistApps/DistApps.html)

until you arrive the "**To share your iOS application.**"

Once you arrive this step, the next screen will ask you for a file name, and an option "Save for entreprise Distribution" will be available *(refer image)*, check for this box and it is here you enter all the information including the most importantly, application URL that must be the same as your bundle
[image: the next screen]

Comment: let me just add as a follow up, that you can not hit an itms-app url in the simulator:  https://github.com/arashpayan/appirater/issues/11  you will need to test from your device.